# How do put items with the same class name in the new div after a certain limit?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

For example in the Model.Examples = List(1,2,3,4,5,6).
I get the data and show it to the user but I have a little problem. I want to show data like under below

```
<div class="x">
   <div class="y">1</div>
   <div class="y">2</div>
   <div class="y">3</div>
</div>
<div class="X">
   <div class="y">4</div>
   <div class="y">5</div>
   <div class="y">6</div>
</div>
```

I try to this but my method is not correct.

```
<div class="x">
   @foreach(var item in Model.Examples)
{
   <div class="y">@item.Number</div>
}
```

When I execute the code, my result is

```
</div class="x">
    <div class="y">1</div>
    <div class="y">2</div>
    <div class="y">3</div>
    <div class="y">4</div>
    <div class="y">5</div>
    <div class="y">6</div>
</div>
```

How can I do it in .NET Core?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`LINQ`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/)'s [`Take`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=net-5.0) and [`Skip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?view=net-5.0):

```
<div class="x">
   @foreach(var item in Model.Examples.Take(Model.Examples.Count/2))
   {
       <div class="y">@item.Number</div>
   }
</div>
<div class="X">
   @foreach(var item in Model.Examples.Skip(Model.Examples.Count/2))
   {
       <div class="y">@item.Number</div>
   }
</div>
```